# ExtJs4 MixedCollection filtering

Tags: extjs, filter, extjs4

```
var pmStore = new storeOfUsers(); // storeOfUsers is an Ext.data.DirectStore with autoLoad: true
console.log(pmStore.data); // is an Ext.util.MixedCollection with 6 items including user_id == 1

var pms = pmStore.data.filter('user_id', 1);
console.log(pms); //is an Ext.util.MixedCollection with length == 0
```

Hello.
After filtering MixedCollection the returned collection is empty although there is a result with user_id == 1. Have I missed something?
Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is the asynchronous loading of the store. You are probably filtering the store before it was loded. I had instances in the past where `console.log()` shows the synchronous data, as if the log is updated once the call completed. I'd try to cancel autoload, and do a manual load instead with a callback where you filter the data.

Comment: console.log(pmStore.data); // shows object with length of 6  
  
console.log(pmStore.data.length); // shows 0  


Izhaki, you are right. 'console.log' shows current object state and not the state when 'console.log' was called. I just tried to filter nothing.  
  

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is the asynchronous loading of the store.

You are probably filtering the store before it was loded. I had instances in the past where console.log() shows incorrectly the synchronous data (as if the log is updated once the call completed).

I'd try to cancel autoload, and do a manual load instead with a callback where you filter the data.

Answer (score 0):

You're filtering your collection whrong, you need to use Ext.util.Filter object to filter your MixedCollection. Here's an example:

```
//your store
var pmStore = new storeOfUsers();

//Create the filter 
var lFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
    property: 'user_id',
    value   : 1
});

//Filter the data
var pms = pmStore.data.filter(lFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks Johan! But still collection lenght is 0. Also tried different options like anyMatch and exactMatch...